# Python: Copy identical .csv files from various folders (each folder has one .csv file) into a single folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The file system is designed as follows in my problem:

```
Main folder -> sub-folder -> data.csv
```

Here, the `Main folder` has several sub-folders where each `sub-folder` has a single `data.csv` file (note that `.csv` files in every sub-folder has same file name as `data.csv`) . For data processing, I need all the `.csv` files to be in a single folder so that I can use the following code (the following code works when I manually copy and rename (since all `.csv` files have identical name) each `.csv` file from sub-folders into a single folder). While renaming the `.csv` files, I used the sub-folder's name, for example: if a sub- folder is named as `a1`, I rename the `.csv` file inside this sub-folder as `a1.csv`.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

path = r'C:\Santobedi' # file path to the folder that contains manually copied and uniquely named .csv files
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
print(all_files)

for file in all_files:
    file_name = os.path.split(file)[-1]
    file_name_path = os.path.join('C:\Santobedi\CNN' + file_name)
    transpose_df = pd.read_csv(file).T
    transpose_df.to_csv(file_name_path)
```

Manually copying and renaming huge files is tiresome. I want to do it in a single go. How can I do it with Python (pandas)?

Comment: why do you want to read/write using pandas and not using `shutil.copy()` or `shuti.move()`? And what is the problem with the code you post here?

Comment: By the way, don't use backslash in windows paths - use raw string or forward slash

Comment: @buran Nothing wrong with the code. I mentioned the code to explain my problem. I tried `shutil.copy(source, destination)`, but its still not helpful since I need to iterate through several sub-folders and rename the .csv file before or after copying into a single folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
MAIN_FOLDER = 'main_folder'
for item in os.listdir(MAIN_FOLDER):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(MAIN_FOLDER, item)):
        source = os.path.join(MAIN_FOLDER, item, 'data.csv')
        destination = os.path.join(MAIN_FOLDER, f'{item}.csv')
        shutil.move(source, destination)
```

Comment: How can I transpose the .csv files from source before moving to destination? In my case, the destination must contain the transposed .csv files from the source.

Comment: in this case reading with pandas, transpose the df and save as csv

Comment: I followed the same approach but got following error: `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 257 fields in line 12, saw 338`

Comment: Check your data on line 12 - probably you have extra `sep` (commas) on that line. Probably you need to specify `quotechar`? Hard to tell without seeing your code and sample data. Maybe ask separate question, because this is not related to your original question.